# How can i intercept a component to check for permission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, react-router

I have lots of static forms which i show the user when he clicks on the main menu and goes to a specific route, what i want to do now is to check when going to a route if that component has permission to be visited, i can do this by doing a simple `post` to server but i am confused and i don't know where should be the place to do this check or `post`.
**Here are some of the solutions i thought of:**
1- Writing a `Higher order component` and wrapping each static component with it
2- creating a base class and making each static form to inherit it while doing this check in the parent class
3- Or maybe using the routes as a solution since i am using the `react-router` ?
I will appreciate any help or tips.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom hook like so:-

```
const useAdmin = (url:string) => {
    const [admin, setAdmin] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        post(url, {some: body}).then(res => {
            setAdmin(res.admin);
        }).catch(err => {
            setAdmin(false);
        });
    }, [])

    return [admin];
}
```

Then use it anywhere:-

```
const mycomponent = props => {
    const [admin] = useAdmin('https://foobar.com/checkPermission');

    //Rest of the logic according to the variable 'admin'
    return (
        <div>
            {
                admin? <div/>:null
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Or think of `admin` as `permission`. Pass it some url for different routes and it will handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar using `react-router` as well. I made my own route component that wraps around `react-router`'s route that checks permissions and conditionally renders the route or redirects.

If you're doing the api call each time, then it would look something close to this.

```
class AppRoute extends Component {
  state = {
    validCredentials: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // api call here + response
    if (ok) {
      this.setState({validCredentials: true})
    } else {
      this.setState({ validCredentials: false})
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { validCredentials } = this.state
    if (validCredentials) {
      return <Route {...this.props} />
    } else if (validCredentials === false) {
      return <Redirect to="somewhere"/>
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely accomplish this using a `Higher Order Component`. Just set a state for the user on login like "admin" or "basic_user." According to this state some buttons or forms are going to be available for the user to access. You can also save these access permissions to your backend and call it in the HOC whenever the user logs in.